# Asyncio: terminating all tasks when one of them throws exception

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, python-asyncio, with-statement

I'm writing python context manager, which runs asynchronous tasks. I want my manager to terminate, if any of its task throws exception. Here is sample code:

```py
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_closed():
      asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

  def __enter__(self):
    return self

  def __exit__(self, excType, excValue, tb):
    try:
      self.loop.run_until_complete(self._exit_loop())
    finally:
      self.loop.close()

    if excType is not None:
      print(excType.__name__, ':', excValue)
      traceback.print_tb(tb)

  async def _exit_loop(self):
    tasks = [task for task in asyncio.all_tasks(self.loop) if
             task is not asyncio.current_task(self.loop)]
    list(map(lambda task: task.cancel(), tasks))

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    self.loop.stop()


  async def func1(self):
    while True:
      print('func1')
      await asyncio.sleep(1)

  async def func2(self):
    i = 5
    while i > 0:
      print('func2')
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
      i -= 1
    raise Exception

  async def _async_start(self):
    self.loop.create_task(self.func1())
    self.loop.create_task(self.func2())

  def start(self):
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self._async_start())

with MyClass() as myClass:
  myClass.start()
  myClass.loop.run_forever()
```

This is output of this script:

```
func1
func2
func1
func2
func1
func2
func1
func2
func1
func2
Task exception was never retrieved
func1
future: <Task finished coro=<MyClass.func2() done, defined at /home/framal/Programy/schnapps/schnapps/bottle/client.py:381> exception=Exception()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/framal/Programy/schnapps/schnapps/bottle/client.py", line 387, in func2
    raise Exception
Exception
func1
func1
func1
.
.
.
```

I tried to use custom exception handlers, but nothing worked - they started running just after terminating the process by force.

How can I pass the exception to the loop, so that it closes all other tasks?

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `run_forever()` there? It does what the name says, running the loop forever, which is why your `__exit__` never gets called. BTW have you tried calling `self.loop.stop()` from the custom exception handler?

Comment: @user4815162342 I did it for example purposes only, I didn't want the program to terminate right after starting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: in Python 3.11 a [TaskGroup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.TaskGroup) was introduced. It has the desired functionality.

**Warning**: If you are looking for a solution for the question in the title and your code does not start the event loop in an unusual way like the code in the question, *do not* stop the loop in the unusual way like in this answer.

---

I do not understand why you are using a context manager (CM) this way.

Anyway, if a CM is given and you put `loop.run_forever()` to the `with` block, the only way I know to exit the loop in this situation so the control is passed to CM's exit function is `loop.stop()`.

Here is a little decorator handling all exceptions except cancellation with `loop.stop()`.

```
def watchdog(afunc):
    @functools.wraps(afunc)
    async def run(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            await afunc(*args, **kwargs)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            raise
        except Exception as err:
            print(f"exception {err}")
            # see the warning
            # normally you should start a shutdown code here
            asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
    return run
```

If you decorate all your coroutines started as tasks by the CM (`func1`, and `func2`), e.g.:

```
@watchdog
async def func2(self):
```

then it will stop after first exception.

Comment: Digging posts from the past, but why such mechanisme isn't native in asyncio ? Why isn't it the default behaviour ? Explicit is better than implicit, if I want to ignore exceptions, event in tasks, I want to do it explicitly. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Vanesbush You are not the only one with doubts. I'm just a programmer, not an expert for designing libraries, but I think the concepts of Trio "nurseries" (and also "cancel scopes") presented in this video (30 minutes, but worth the time!) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLkfnc_UMcE are clearly better than what we have in the standard library now.